# Git Submodules - Updating and Commiting changes

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm reading Phil's blog post about GIT submodules, which will be really helpful to me.
http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2011/09/managing-codeigniter-packages-with-git-submodules

I'm wondering about one step in the process of updating a submodule:  When you make changes to a submodule and go to check status, it says you're not in a working tree ("you have no head"?).  You're then supposed to "git checkout master" - ??? - but won't that undo all the changes you made and return your submodule to a previous state?

---

So with submodules my understanding is you do the following:

1.)  Clone submodule

2.)  Init and Update submodule ** you only do this once?

3.)  Make changes

4.)  Checkout "master" on submodule ** this won't jack you up?

5.)  Commit submodule

6.)  Push submodule ** can you commit primary project w/out pushing submodule?

7.)  Commit primary project

Just trying to clear things up in my head.

---

EDIT:  I guess there is a difference between cloning a submodule into a project versus pulling an entire superproject.  Looks like the "git submodule init && update" is only necessary when pulling entire projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My starting workflow

1. Clone a primary project
2. Init and Update submodule
3. Go inside interesting submodule and do **git checkout -b feature_branch**
4. Do changes
5. Commit them
6. Push them
7. Go up to the primary project
8. git add && git commit && git push

Beware! You **can** push the primary project to some publicly available repository without step 6 but you really **should not**. Because it became unusable for outsiders.

My basic workflow (suppose that we already implemented several features)

1. Go to primary repository and checkout desired branch|tag|commit
2. Update submodules (this checkouts desired versions of all submodules
3. Go inside interesting submodule and do **git checkout -b feature_branch**
4. Do changes
5. Commit them
6. Push them
7. Go up to the primary project
8. git add && git commit && git push